# Error while getting details of the particular system through python script

Tags: python, win32com

I am using a [script](http://pastebin.com/RXH4b11v) for getting system details. its all working fine in almost 1000 systems, but in one system its getting the below error.

```
File "SystemDetails.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "<COMObject WbemScripting.SWbemLocator>", line 5, in ConnectServer
  File "\\sfs\show_time\Showtime_Package\showtime\Modules\x32\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 272, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'SWbemLocator', u'Not found ', None, 0, -2147217406), None)
```

when i checked the system properties of that system, i found out that only ram is displaying. In rest of the systems both ram and processer information is displayed. for your reference i have attached both system details of my system and the the issue system.

[image] [image]

Can anyone help me to find out the problem and the solution fot it

Comment: Is there CPU information in Registry in  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor` folder/subfolders?

Comment: @ton1c I Just found out that in that system there is four folders naming [0,1,2,3]. and when i click the folder i am able to see the processer information.

Comment: It's looks like it's not code error (due to that Windows itself can't get the information). I run across a lot of [posts](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cpu+information+missing+windows+xp) with problem like yours. Maybe try to look through them. The only solution that I found was working, was reinstalling the whole system...

Comment: @ton1c Thanks for the reply. if you come accross any solution please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because of corrupted WMI services.

Try installing Microsoft WMI tools and register WMI entries in registry.

This will solve you issue.

Comment: Yes this solved the problem. Thanks for the solution. The problem was WMI services was courupted. Reinstalling the WMI tools solved the problem.